# How to detect current stream in kernel code?

Tags: cuda

Is it possible to check within the cuda kernel in which stream (https://developer.download.nvidia.com/CUDA/training/StreamsAndConcurrencyWebinar.pdf) it is executing? In particular, I am interested in checking if I am running in default stream or not.

I am thinking that potentially, this information could be extracted from %envreg or %pt registers https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/parallel-thread-execution/index.html#identifiers but didn't find any documentation on this.

Comment: Streams are a host side abstraction. I'm guessing the lack of document is a pretty clear indication what you want to do isn't possible

Comment: Just pass the stream as additional kernel argument?

Answer (score 2):

There [currently isn't any method](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#api-reference) to retrieve a host based stream in CUDA device code.

As suggested in the comments, you may be able to serve your needs by passing the needed information via kernel arguments.